# Dimension of a subspace generated by an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a hermitian matrix and $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, why is it obvious that $W=\{\alpha v \vert \alpha \in \mathbb{C}\} = v \mathbb{C}$ is of dimension $1$?

Comment: *Any* subspace generated by one (nonzero) vector is one-dimensional. This has nothing to do with eigenvectors.

Comment: Because all its elements are spanned by **one** vector, namely $v$...

Comment: **HINT**: Can you find a basis for your subspace?

Answer (score 1):

It is true for all $v \neq 0$ (not necessarily eigenvectors of $A$).